# Install theme on multiple domains

Tags: directory

i'm hosting several sites. they all have the same base theme that i need to install. I want to develop this theme and have them updated on all the sites simultaneously.

I have the following folder structure

```
/theme/
 \ mytheme

/domain/ 
   \ foo.com 
   \ foobar.com
   \ foosite.com
```

Would there be any issue with symlinking each site with my theme into each site's `wp-config/theme/` folder? Not interested in multisite. Had to developed sites seperately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will work fine - just make sure they all have read and write access to that shared folder. The symlink command should be:

```
ln -s
```

StackOverflow question: [Can two different WordPress blogs on the same server use a common theme folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997007/can-two-different-wordpress-blogs-on-the-same-server-use-a-common-theme-folder)

Answer (score -1):

Or, do a multisite install -- the themes directory is shared by all sites and each theme can be enabled on a site by site basis.

Comment: right. but that's not the question.